# consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Tags: xcode, swift3

I'm creating table view in xCode in Swift 3.0, but this error kept on showing up. And when I fixed it with another ';', it show up another error "Expected declaration". 
Can anyone help me with this problem?

[image: This is my code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type operator in Swift is `->` not `-&gt` may be you have copy and paste code from the browser or some where else so simply replace it with `->`. Also in Swift 3 signature of these methods is changed so it should be like.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Swift. Thanks for fixing it for me!!

Comment: @windc Welcome mate :) Keep in mind that this will populate empty tableView :)